# What's the meaning of "ride secure"?

Tags: meaning, grammar

> port :  a place where ships may **ride secure** from storms - Definition of port by Merriam-Webster.

I have two questions.

1. What's the meaning of "ride" and "secure" in this sentence?
2. "secure" is used as verb or adjective. Then in this sentence, form of "ride secure" is [verb] + [adjective/verb]. Isn't it wrong in grammar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're parsing the sentence slightly incorrectly.  It isn't one single phrase "ride secure", it's "ride / secure from storms".

**Ride** simply has its dictionary definition here:

> [3 a :  to lie moored or anchored](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/ride)

**Secure** is an adjective, as you noted, which means "safe":

> [2 a :  free from danger](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/secure)

So the correct way to parse the sentence is:

a place where ships may **lie moored or anchored** *in a way that is* **safe from storms**.

Comment: So "safe" is for "a place", NOT for "ride", right? So, 1. a place where ships may ride. 2. a place safe from storms. The sentence have these two meanings, right?

Comment: Essentially, yes.  It's "a place for ships to ride that is safe from storms".